# libev c++ wrapper function_thunk

Tags: c++

```
void set_ (const void *data, void (*cb)(EV_P_ ev_watcher *w, int revents)) throw ()
{
  this->data = (void *)data;
  ev_set_cb (static_cast<ev_watcher *>(this), cb);
}

// function callback
template<void (*function)(watcher &w, int)>
void set (void *data = 0) throw ()
{
  set_ (data, function_thunk<function>);
}

template<void (*function)(watcher &w, int)>
static void function_thunk (EV_P_ ev_watcher *w, int revents)
{
  function
    (*static_cast<watcher *>(w), revents);
}
```

Hi,

I'm using libev's C++ wrapper ev++.h.
There is this piece of code in ev++.h that I know how to use as an API, but don't fully understand. 
I can set up a Ctrl-C watcher in the event loop as follows:

```
ev::sig signal_watcher(evloop); 
signal_watcher.set<sigint_cb>(); 
signal_watcher.start(SIGINT);
```

where sigint_cb's function signature is :

```
void sigint_cb(ev::sig &w, int revents)
```

Can someone explain why **function_thunk** can magically cast my sigint_cb function signature to

```
void (*cb)(EV_P_ ev_watcher *w, int revents)
```

What C++ sorcery is this? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**function_thunk** doesn't magically cast **sigint_cb** signature to `void (*cb)(EV_P_ ev_watcher *w, int revents)` it just call **sigint_cb** with properly casted arguments.

From the beginning, **function_thunk** is a function template which can be intstantiated with function pointer of type `void (*)(watcher &w, int)`.
So basically when you will write `function_thunk<sigint_cb>` somewhere in your code, compiler will create corresponding **function_thunk** instance which will be looking like this:

```cpp
void function_thunk (EV_P_ ev_watcher *w, int revents)
{
    sigint_cb(*static_cast<watcher *>(w), revents);
}
```

Also note that in you example `ev::sig` and `watcher` are the same types, otherwise template argument deduction/substitution for **function_thunk** would failed.

Comment: Thanks. So if I think in terms of std::bind, I am binding sigint_cb to function_thunk , right? Cause it really feels like what std::bind does.